# Weird translation behaviour with Rails I18n default language

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localization, internationalization

I am using I18n gem for the first time. I am creating a website using two languages (English and Bengali). So I did everything according to I18n api. Now everything works fine except one. My default action (or you can say `root :to => my_default_options`) is having some issues with translation. My default i18n language is English. But The texts from default layout (`application.html.erb`) are by default translated in Bengali in this action. I repeat only the parts from default layout. Other texts from that action's view file are translating fine. On the other hand, texts from application's default layout is translating fine in English and Bengali. The problem occurs only in my default action.

Though it is a complicated problem, I have uploaded complete source of my [app](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzvsXmKfN4BQRzU4U3owcTU5LVE/edit?usp=sharing). (Warning: the app is not complete, so everything may not work)

I am not sure which files are necessary to post here. I am having this problem in microblogs controller. In "new" action. Here it is..

```
class MicroblogsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :auth, :only => [:up, :down] 
  before_filter :set_locale

  def new
    @text = Microblog.new
    @all = all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
    @top = Microblog.top_rated.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
  end

  def create
    @text = Microblog.new(params[:text])
    if Captcha::valid?(session,params)
      if @text.save
        flash[:notice] = "DONE!"
        redirect_to( @text)
      else
        #redirect_to(  :action => 'new' )
        render 'new'
      end
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Wrong Answer. Try Again!"
      redirect_to :back 
    end

  end

  def show
    @text = Microblog.find(params[:id])
    @com = @text.comments.sorted.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
    @rating = (@text.up - @text.down)
  end


  def up
    @text = Microblog.find(params[:id])
    @text.update_attributes(params[@text.up += 1])
    @text.update_attributes(params[@text.rate += 1])

    @a.push(@text.id)

    session[:token] = @a
    if @a.size > 5
        @a.delete_at(0)
    end

    redirect_to( :action => 'show', :id => @text.id)
  end

  def down


    @text.update_attributes(params[@text.down += 1])
    @text.update_attributes(params[@text.rate -= 1])

    @a.push(@text.id)
    session[:token] = @a
    if @a.size > 5
        @a.delete_at(0)
    end
    redirect_to( :action => 'show', :id => @text.id)
  end


    private

      def auth
            @text = Microblog.find(params[:id])
            @a = session[:token].to_a

            if @a.include?(@text.id)
                redirect_to( :action => 'show', :id => @text.id)
                return false
            else
                return true
            end
      end



end
```

I have set i18n option in application controller.

```
def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
end
```

my i18n configuration from config.application.rb

```
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]
config.i18n.default_locale = :'en'
```

and here is the lines from view/layouts/application.html.erb. these are the lines I am having problem with

```
<li><%= link_to("#{ t :Home}", :action => 'new') %></li>
    <%= I18n.locale %> (to see the value of i18n)
```

This problem only occurs while rendering microblogs/new action. The text ":Home" translates into bengali always and shows the value of the i18n variable is bn (bengali). But other parts of /view/microblogs/new.html.erb translate parfectly

Comment: Please consider providing the parts of code you consider related. The question can not be answered like this.

Comment: added but not sure that those are the necessary codes